# About $\int_{\mathcal{X}} h(\mathbf{x}) g(\Arrowvert\mathbf{x}\Arrowvert)d\mathbf{x} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^{+}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a real-valued function such that $\textstyle\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{N-1} g(t)dt < \infty$. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Is it possible to say that:
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} h(\mathbf{x}) g(\Arrowvert\mathbf{x}\Arrowvert)d\mathbf{x} = 0, \Rightarrow h(\mathbf{x}) \equiv h(\Arrowvert\mathbf{x}\Arrowvert),
\end{equation*}
where $\Arrowvert\mathbf{x}\Arrowvert$ is the Euclidean norm of $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$?

Comment: what is the set $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the whole $\mathbb{R}^N$...

Comment: Why is the quantifier $\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}$ there when you have already integrated out the $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: Yes, you are rigth!